How can I log and handle database connection interruptions in a Drizzle ORM?
I'm working on a Fastify server and using Drizzle ORM with postgres-js for database interactions. I have a custom plugin that sets up the main database connection and attaches it to the Fastify instance. I want to detect if the connection is interrupted, log the error, and execute some custom logic (like reconnecting or notifying the application).
Here’s the current setup for my mainDbPlugin:
import type { PostgresJsDatabase } from 'drizzle-orm/postgres-js'
import type { FastifyInstance, FastifyPluginAsync } from 'fastify'
import { drizzle } from 'drizzle-orm/postgres-js'
import fp from 'fastify-plugin'
import postgres from 'postgres'
import { mainTables } from '.'

interface DrizzlePluginOptions {
  url: string
  poolSize: number
}
declare module 'fastify' {
  interface FastifyInstance {
    mainDb: PostgresJsDatabase<typeof mainTables>
  }
}

const mainDbPlugin: FastifyPluginAsync<DrizzlePluginOptions> = fp(
  async (server: FastifyInstance, opts: DrizzlePluginOptions) => {
    const queryClient = postgres(opts.url, {
      max: opts.poolSize,
    })

    const db = drizzle(queryClient, { schema: mainTables })

    server.decorate('mainDb', db)

    server.addHook('onReady', async () => {
      await queryClient`SELECT 1`
      server.log.info('Main database connection established')
    })

    server.addHook('onClose', async () => {
      await queryClient.end()
    })
  },
  {
    name: 'main-db-plugin',
  },
)

export default mainDbPlugin

My primary issue is that postgres-js does not seem to have an .on event handler for connection errors, which I’d typically use to listen for connection interruptions and run custom error-handling logic.
How can I monitor for connection interruptions and handle reconnection logic in this setup? I need to:

Log any connection interruptions
Run specific logic to either attempt reconnection or handle the
disconnection gracefully

Any suggestions or alternative approaches to achieve this within Fastify and Drizzle ORM would be much appreciated.
